# define a new walking route that doesn't exist on Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering if there's any way to 
define a new walking route that doesn't exist on Google maps with JavaScript Google map api.

It is a very tight walking route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter a route by specifying Waypoints. As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions):

> Waypoints alter a route by routing it through the specified location(s)

You can read more about using Waypoints in Javascript [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints).